# "anyone who is qualified" or "anyone whom is qualified"?

Tags: whom

So my class has this question, which is:

> Probably it can be anyone (who/whom) is qualified, perhaps even Mr Capp.
>   *(Found on page 112 in Grammar for Writing Workbook.)*

I personally put *who*, because the way I'd phrase that into a sentence is like such:

> He/She is qualified for the job.

However, my fellow students say because it's a product of a preposition it should be phrased like:

> The one qualified for the job is him/her.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Any question asking about _whom_ is a trick question. The answer is always "If the _who/whom_ is the object of a preposition, use _whom_. Otherwise, always use _who_." Object of a preposition is the only situation where _whom_ is **required**; everywhere else it's either optional or ungrammatical. So, always use _who_, and only use _whom_ when it's the object of a preposition -- and avoid that construction; you can always strand the preposition: _To whom are you speaking? = Who are you speaking to?_ Executive summary: Don't use _whom_. It's dead.

Comment: Grammatically here, *anyone* is the object of the clause *"it can be anyone"*, but *who* is the subject of the clause *"who is qualified"*. It gets tricky when the same word (usually *who(m)ever*) is both the subject and the object: *"Kudos to who(m)ever can answer this question."*

Comment: @Peter: the rule works the same with _whoever_. Don't use _whomever_ unless it's the object of a preposition. The _whoever_ in your example is a  subject (of _can_), not an object; the whole S is the object of the preposition. One does have to be able to distinguish clause objects from pronoun objects; but if there's any problem, go with _who_ anyway. _Whom_ is just kept around to make up distractors for examinations.